# Application Launcher Using Assigned Access ( Windows 10 )

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I have had a look around but I am coming up blank. I have three applications I'd like a user to be able to access, However it appears you can only have one application in the Assigned Access mode.

Is it possible to use an app launcher (Like RocketDock) as the selected application in Assigned Access Mode so that the user can select between the three applications?

Failing that, Can anyone point me in the direction of the documentation that explains how I can assign an application that's not in the available applications list.

Sorry if I seem unclear! It's rather hard to explain what I am trying to do.

I have been informed that a custom shell is more what I am looking for but thought i'd ask here and get some other opinions before I decide what to do.

Comment: My comments over on [SO] still apply :) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810123/application-launcher-using-assigned-access-windows-10)

Comment: Note that my recommendation of [Shell Launcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher) is actually a Windows configuration option that would allow you to use RocketDock or similar as the shell, instead of the standard Windows Explorer - it's not a separate program that you have to buy. That wasn't clear in my SO comments.